# Titan Attacks Screen Positioning

Tags: ps3, titan-attacks

I have a problem with screen positioning in titan attacks. Parts of the game screen are cut-off from my TV. When the game first started it gave me an option to adjust it but I clicked X without first reading what it said.

Now when I open the game in the initial screen I can only see the Play option (although there are clearly more since I can go down using my D-pad) and I cannot find the settings to re-adjust it. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved the same problem and I am happy to share it with you. In the Menu screen, where you can see just "Play", go right twice with your d-pad, then X. You will get the Options Menu and your Screen Size option. Adjust accordingly (0.640 for me) and enjoy!